# How to clear input text

Tags: jquery

How to clear appended input text when starting to type in the search box.
https://jsfiddle.net/adampavlov/u4hz3k6d/1/

```
$('a.dropdown-item').click(function(){
    var search_txt = $(this).text();
    $('.searchbox-input').val(search_txt);
  });

  $('.searchbox-input').focus(function(){
    $(this).val();
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Just pass null value to input on focus

```
$('a.dropdown-item').click(function(){
    var search_txt = $(this).text();
    $('.searchbox-input').val(search_txt);
  });

  $('.searchbox-input').focus(function(){
    $(this).val('');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the value of focused input as empty

```
  $('.searchbox-input').focus(function(){
    $(this).val(''); //setting the input field as empty using that single  or double quotes 
  });
```